# EPIPE (Broken Pipe)

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider

I'm attempting to build a capability that allows a `ContentProvider` to extract a thumbnail from a raw image.

Here is the implementation:

```
@Override
public ParcelFileDescriptor openFile(@NonNull Uri uri, @NonNull String mode) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    [Uri handling stuff]
    return openPipeHelper(image, "unused", null, null, this);
}

@Override
public void writeDataToPipe(@NonNull ParcelFileDescriptor output, @NonNull Uri uri, @NonNull String mimeType, @Nullable Bundle opts, @Nullable Void args)
{
    final String where = Meta.URI_SELECTION;
    final String[]  whereArgs = new String[]{uri.toString()};
    Meta.ImageType imageType = null;
    try(Cursor metaCursor = query(
            Meta.META_URI, new String[] { Meta.TYPE },
            where, whereArgs, null, null))
    {
        if (metaCursor != null && metaCursor.moveToFirst()) 
            imageType = Meta.ImageType.fromInt(metaCursor.getInt(metaCursor.getColumnIndex(Meta.TYPE)));
    }

    byte[] thumbData;
    //noinspection ConstantConditions
    try(AssetFileDescriptor fd = getContext().getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(uri, "r"))
    {
        if (imageType == null || imageType == Meta.ImageType.UNPROCESSED)
        {
            imageType = ImageUtil.getImageType(getContext(), uri);

            // Update the image type
            ContentValues value = new ContentValues(1);
            value.put(Meta.TYPE, imageType.getValue());
            update(Meta.META_URI, value, where, whereArgs);
        }

        switch(imageType)
        {
            case TIFF:
                thumbData = ImageUtil.getTiffImage(fd.getParcelFileDescriptor().getFd());
                break;
            default:
                thumbData = ImageUtil.getRawThumb(fd.getParcelFileDescriptor().getFd());
                break;
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, ": Failed to open: " + uri, e);
        return;
    }

    if (thumbData == null)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, ": Failed to extract: " + uri);
        return;
    }

    try (FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(output.getFileDescriptor()))
    {
        fout.write(thumbData, 0, thumbData.length);  // FAILS HERE
        Log.d(TAG, "--End openFile: " + uri);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "*Fail openFile: " + uri, e);
    }
}
```

The code used a `PipeDataWriter` to place a byte[] from a native (jni) decoded thumbnail `ImageUtil.getRawThumb` into the read side of a pipe `fout.write(thumbData, 0, thumbData.length)` that will feed `openFile`.

However, when I load a few hundred images I'm finding 5-10% of images fail with errors similar to:

> 03-24 23:34:49.022 26890-28130/com.anthonymandra.rawdroidpro
>   E/MetaProvider: *Fail openFile:
>   content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/0000-0000%3A_largeSet/document/0000-0000%3A_largeSet%2FKyoto-255.CR2
>                                                                                **java.io.IOException: write failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)**
>                                                                                    at libcore.io.IoBridge.write(IoBridge.java:498)
>                                                                                    at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:186)
>                                                                                    at
>   **com.anthonymandra.content.MetaProvider.writeDataToPipe(MetaProvider.java:270)**
>                                                                                    at
>   com.anthonymandra.content.MetaProvider.writeDataToPipe(MetaProvider.java:40)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.content.ContentProvider$1.doInBackground(ContentProvider.java:1712)
>                                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
>                                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>                                                                                    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
>                                                                                    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
>                                                                                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>                                                                                 Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: write failed: EPIPE (Broken
>   pipe)
>                                                                                    at libcore.io.Posix.writeBytes(Native Method)
>                                                                                    at libcore.io.Posix.write(Posix.java:271)
>                                                                                    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.write(BlockGuardOs.java:313)
>                                                                                    at libcore.io.IoBridge.write(IoBridge.java:493)
>                                                                                    at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:186) 
>                                                                                    at
>   com.anthonymandra.content.MetaProvider.writeDataToPipe(MetaProvider.java:270) 
>                                                                                    at
>   com.anthonymandra.content.MetaProvider.writeDataToPipe(MetaProvider.java:40) 
>                                                                                    at
>   android.content.ContentProvider$1.doInBackground(ContentProvider.java:1712) 
>                                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295) 
>                                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
>                                                                                    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
>                                                                                    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
>                                                                                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

`ContentResolver.openInputStream` is being called by [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide), which is using up to 'core-count' threads to load images.

Previously I just loaded the thumbnail via a custom loader for Glide without issue.  I'm guessing there's some concurrency limitation to the underlying "pipe" system.  Most questions on this topic don't get a satisfying answer.  Is there anything obviously wrong here or am I exceeding the capabilities of the system?